# How to trigger parent componentDidUpdate by click in child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, parent-child, react-class-based-component

In my parent component, I have a **class component** called **ListOfItems.js**, that lists a bunch of objects like so:

```
class ListOfItems extends Component {
  construction (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      objectList: []
    }
  }
}

// This gets the list of objects to display
componentDidMount() {
   this.getObjectList();
}

componentDidUpdate(_prevProps, prevState) {

  if( this.state.ObjectList !== prevState.ObjectList) {

     // this is called infinitely which is a problem
     console.log("entered");
     this.getObjectList();
  }
}

getObjectList = () => {
  const input = { id_for_this_list: id }

  fetch( connectToApi, {
     method: "PUT",
     headers: { //stuff}
     body: JSON.stringify(input)
  })
     .then(res => //)
     .then(result => 
        if( result.length >= 0) {
            this.setState( {...this.state, objectList: result });
        }   
     )
     .catch(err=>{console.error(err)});
}

render () {
  return (
    {this.state.objectList.map(item) => {
      <Object 
        objectList={this.objectList}
        data={item}
       //few other props here
      >
    }}
  )
}
```

In my child component, I have a **functional component** called **Object.js**. In this, I have a **delete functionality**, where if the user selected the "x" icon on the object, that object is deleted from the list.

```
// 'x' image that, when clicked on, deletes object from list of objects
// (heavily simplified for stackOverFlow)

<img onClick= {() => { deleteObject() })>

const deleteObject() = () => {
   fetch( connectToApi, {
     method: "DELETE"
   })
      .then(res => //)
      .then(result => //deletion made and confirmed succesful)
      .catch(err => console.error(err))
}
```

How do I trigger the **componentDidUpdate()** in **ListOfItems.js** (parent), when I **click** on the **"x"** on an **Object** (child)?

Btw, the **parent** must be a **class component** and the **child** must be a **functional component**, unfortunately.

Comment: "Object" is a terrible idea for ***any*** identifier in Javascript. Why would you do that to yourself? React components are React components, whether or not they are class or function components is simply an implementation detail. It shouldn't matter at all. The parent needs to pass down a callback to `Object` component for it to call for anything to happen in the parent component. What are you passing down as props?

Comment: For the sake of simplicity and understanding, I named the object, Object. Yes, I now know that functional and class components are merely different in syntax, upon some research... Anyways, I resolved this issue with @S. Argentina's comments below. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never appear to set the state for your parent component when you call `getObjectList` so that could be an issue for you, I'm not sure if you're left it out of this excerpt on purpose.

Either way, you'll need to pass down a function from the parent component that sets the state held in the parent component. That will cause the parent to rerender.

If you don't want to change the state you can potentially call a function that you pass from the parent that forces a refresh, but this wouldn't be ideal.

```
parentResetFunction = () => {
   this.forceUpdate()
}
```

Comment: I forgot to include the setState inside of getObjectList! Thanks for pointing that out. I have fixed that in the code above.

Comment: I agree with you -- I would not want to do a forceUpdate(), since this is risky, albeit a way to update the component.

Comment: For passing down the function from the parent that sets the state held in the parent component, how would I go about doing this? The parent is a class component and the child is a functional component, btw (I cannot change this).

Comment: You need to create a function in your parent component, similar to `getObjectList`, except in this function you call `this.setState(etc)` to make your state changes. Then take that function and pass it down as a prop to the child component and run the function from the child component.

Comment: The names I used below are just as an example

`
<Object 

        objectList={this.objectList}

        data={item}

        handleStateChange={this.functonThatChangesState}

       //few other props here

      >

`

Comment: You are a freakin lifesaver!!! Thank you so much. I didn't know that a function call in a child component could trigger a function in the parent, via props. I spent hours on this and you saved me. THANK YOU!!

Comment: No problem! It was tough starting out, so I'm glad I could help!